# How to make jQuery equal column script run on window resize?

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window-resize

I'm running a jQuery script to set equal height divs in a row across multiple rows.

Here's a link to an extract of the code I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/F8QHd/2/

For the script I've used the technique in this post at CSS Tricks http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

Can anyone tell me how to amend the script so that as the window is resized it still works? At the moment, it works on page load but I don't know how to trigger it based on window resize. The script uses `$(window).resize(function() {} );` so I'm not sure why this doesn't work?

Comment: with which browser do you have a problem?

Comment: It seems to not work in any browser so far as I can see.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see that it doesn't work. 
You would set up resize then trigger it so that it works on load without duplicating that instruction.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    columnConform();
}).trigger('resize');
```

Just one note - equalising the elements causes the window to change size and you're going to hit problems when it recurses a few times before it settles. I solved this by adding a timeout on the equal heights function.

I already wrote a similar extension to jquery. If you're interested it's here
[Equal Height Rows for Fluid Width Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167277/equal-height-rows-for-fluid-width-elements/14167351#comment20553141_14167351)

Comment: Thanks - I tried changing the line in the jFiddle as you suggested (see http://jsfiddle.net/F8QHd/3/) and the text still breaks out of the first column when the window size is reduced. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Oh i see, your heights aren't resetting. I would try setting them to auto before finding the tallest.